# Deploying Dash app in Azure, remains Loading

Tags: python, flask, azure-web-app-service, plotly-dash, azure-deployment

I`m trying to deploy a simple Dash App in Azure, and I followed the tutorial below:

https://www.phillipsj.net/posts/deploying-dash-to-azure-without-using-docker/

It works perfectly in my localhost, but when I try to deploy it in Azure the site shows only the message: Loading...

[image]

If I try to deploy a Flask App in Azure (https://medium.com/@nikovrdoljak/deploy-your-flask-app-on-azure-in-3-easy-steps-b2fe388a589e) it works perfectly fine.

Could you please give me any indication why this migh happen? Is there any difference between deploying Flask and Dash in Azure?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Any updates? Do you solve the problem? Or what exactly you want?

Comment: @CharlesXu, thank you for your answer. I ended up including a Dash app inside a Flask app, similar to this https://hackersandslackers.com/plotly-dash-with-flask/

Comment: It's not bad. You can do any attempt as you want :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I recommend you test all the applications locally before you publish it to the Azure Web App. If it does not work fine locally, fix it until it succeeds. For the link you provided in the question, I test it on my side and it does not work fine. With checking, it loses the package dash-renderer. So you can install it and freeze it into the requirements and test it locally. Or directly append it into the requirements.txt:

```
dash-renderer==0.13.0
```

Then publish it to the Azure Web App and it will work fine like this:

[image]

If you have any more questions, please let me know.